Clarification on how feature extraction works in feature extraction with frequencies
I am following DeepLearning.ai's NLP first course on Coursera and the first week talks about feature extraction that maps text from this corpus.

to a dictionary  (word, sentiment) to frequencies in this image.

They later mention that we need a vector of [bias, positive word frequencies, negative word frequencies]. What I don't get is how their values were calculated from this table.

For positive frequencies, I get 3+3+3+3+1+1 = 14 and not 8.
For negative frequencies, I get 3+3+2+3+3+1+1+1 = 17 and not 11.

How should I be counting these frequencies? What seems to give me the same answer is to avoid counting the frequencies of the words I and am when the words show up again. Is this how it is done?
Positive frequencies

Negative frequencies


The links you shared links to Coursera, which we cannot access. My guess based on the information you've shared is that the original dictionary is created by counting the number of times the different words occur in the whole dataset (i.e. in all sentences). To then get the vector of a specific sentence you simply only include the numbers/counts from the dictionary for the words that are in the sentence. The words 'happy' and 'because' are not included for the example sentence because they are not in the sentence, which will give a sum of $3 + 3 + 1 + 1 + 0 + 0 = 8$.

Thanks. I added the corpus that is needed for clarity.

Is the approach though that we need to get the set of words without duplication and then use those frequencies?

Indeed, you simply take all words that are present in the corpus and count the number of times the word occurs in the positive and negative tweets.
